# Getting the total number of checked items from a listview in Android

Tags: java, android

How to get the total number of checked items from a listview in Android? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

There's `getCheckedItemCount()`. You could also call `getCheckedItemIds()` on it and then call `length()` on that.  (You can get the ListView to call this on by doing a findViewById on it, or by calling `getListView()` inside the ListActivity.)

Answer (score 0):

or you can try a loop to check what all items are selected.